# Multiplexing cell of matrix

Tags: multiplexer, matrix

in a project I am developing I have a matrix of cells, each cell containing 3 buttons (it will be more eventually, around 10). The schematic is like this:

[image]

I want to read each one of the cells, and in each cell I want to read each one of the buttons. To do it, I want to multiplex each cell, and read the first button on the MuxBTN1 pin, the second on the MuxBTN2 pin, etc. I also want it to be expandable, the matrix will be NxM sizewise (the number of cells will be around 30-40).
Each button is a bit, each cell is an 10 bit number, I want to map all the cells numbers to a bi dimensional matrix in code. Speed is not very important.

What would be a good approach to this problem? Everything I have found on the internet was about multiplexing an led matrix, which is not the same. Thank you!

Comment: You will have 8 buttons per cell. But how many cells (what's the maximum number you need your design to allow)? And how often do you need to read the buttons?

Comment: Yes, around 8-10 buttons per cell. There will also be around 30-40 cells. The frequency can be pretty low, but also not super slow. Around every 500ms-1s.

Comment: I understand reading buttons but what does reading a cell mean (if it doesn’t mean reading the buttons in a cell). Do you need to mention cells? Why not just say that you want to read 40 odd buttons? Also, why do the buttons need to be grounded?

Comment: Also, if there are some other limitations on the inputs (like only 1 button per cell might be pushed at a given time) you might get further optimizations.

Comment: Multiple buttons can be pressed at the same time, from multiple cells.

Comment: I am thinking on using an 8bit shift-out register for selecting the row, and using a 16bit shift-in register for each column (cells buttons), would something like that work?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume, each switch is independent, or say, multiple switches can close at the same time, a structure with two levels of mux can be used. A 8 (N) to 1 mux is used for each cell, and another 8 (M) to 1 mux is used for all the cells. The processor needs to set the mux to 00, 01, ..., 0N, 10, 11, ..., 1N, ..., M0, M1, ..., MN, and read each value and decide whether each SW is on or off.

Comment: Is there any way to not be necessary to use a multiplexer for each cell?

Comment: Why not? An eight to 1 mux is a simple and inexpensive IC. For 8x8 matrix, you need nice ICs, and 7 GPIOs from uP.

Comment: Ok, I will give it some thought, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use shift registers (for example, [74LV165](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LV165.pdf)) instead of multiplexers if the goal is to do this with the fewest pins of your micro and fewest external chips.

Exactly how you arrange them depends on details of your requirements you haven't shared. You could make one big shift-register chain if you'll always want to read all the buttons at the same time. Or break them up into banks of whatever size needed if you will sometimes want to read only a subset of the buttons.

Comment: Each button is a bit, each cell is an 10 bit number, I want to map all the cells numbers to a bi dimensional matrix in code. Speed is not very important. I can see shift registers being used for an array of cells, but can't see for matrix. Would it be necessary to use a shift register per cell?

Comment: If each cell is a 10-bit number, why did you say the max number of buttons per cell is 8? Remember we can't read your mind and the only things we know about your problem is what you tell us. Edit your question post to include all the information needed to answer it.

Comment: I said around 8 in the post, in the comments I said 8-10. Sorry!

Comment: @RicardoFalcão, please **edit your question** to include **all** the information needed to give you a useful answer.

Comment: RE "I can see shift registers being used for an array of cells, but can't see for matrix.", you'll just need to work out a way to order the cells so they can be read serially. Even if you used multiplexers, you'd need to decide an order to sweep through the matrix, reading one button at a time.

Comment: Ok, I will give it some thought, thank you for your time.